# Choose the term that best sums up a set of things

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice

I have a question about using a word. The sentence I consider is:

> I built a model to classify messages related to economic issues.

With the expression *economic issues* I want to include the following arguments: GDP growth, economic aid coming from the European Union, hiring boom, company closures due to the pandemic, etc.

Maybe *economic themes* or *economic topics* or *economic leaning*? Or is simply *economy* sufficient and understandable?

Comment: It will depend on the context. For example, if you are emphasizing the categorization of influences, it might be Categories. If you are emphasizing something else, you might use something else. Factors, influences, subjects, parameters, there are many.

Comment: I need a term to describe what I have done in the categorization of messages (tweets to be precise). I give some examples. For example "ECB raises interest rates", "My company has laid off 10% of its staff" and "Wages increased by 2.5%" are all in the "economy" category. So my sentence is: "I built a model to classify messages related to ..." economy? economic issues? economic themes? Which of these? Or what else? I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: You seem to have a very broad categorization. I doubt that there is a single term that can fully describe everything that you have included without implying things that you have not included. Based on your examples, something like “current economic news and related topics” might work. “Economics” seems too broad because your examples do not include economic theory or economic history.

Comment: I wouldn't use "economics", which is a more scientific term, but "economy". Wouldn't that be okay either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use any of those in some form. **Issues** is a great choice.

However, I think your sentence needs additional clarification:

> I built a model to classify messages related to economic issues.

It's not clear whether the classification model is related to economic issues or the messages are related to economic issues. If it's the model, then you might be throwing out messages that don't relate to economic issues. If it's the messages, then they are defined as already being related to economic issues so it's just a question of figuring out which one. Maybe it's a technicality, but you might want to be more specific:

> I built a model to assign each message to one of eight categories based on the economic issue discussed in the content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for a shorter sentence than you wrote (as it should be a resume achievement). However, I try to explain myself better, since I did not understand your answer very well. The purpose of the model is to identify which tweets are about the economy. So yes, the model could identify a tweet that is not economic as "economic" but also identify a tweet that is economic as "non economic". So yes, the model can get the classification wrong. Does this change your answer?

Comment: I’d use economic information or economic data. An issue is something on which reasonable people may disagree.

Comment: I think we answered this in the other question.